# Unable to recieve given number of entry data: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've written some code which automatically creates entry boxes based on a numberical user input.

When trying to `.get()` the data from these entry boxes through a regular button command I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Entry
```

Heres the code:

```
ply_name = []
ply_θ = []
tk = []
i = 0

        for i in name_count:
            n_n = (n_count[i]).get()
            n.append(n_n)


            n_a = (a_count[i]).get()
            a.append(n_a)

            n_t = (t_count[i]).get()
            t.append(n_t)

            i += 1
            if i == given_count:
                break
```

I know that the given_count value is correct as it's used further up to add the entry boxes in question to the my grid system.

The error seems to lie in the i value.
No matter how I try lay this out aslong as I cann i as the index value I get the same error.

Any help would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of your Entries you need to keep a reference.
if you just stor a number or a charakter it does not have any reference.
here is x the reference.

Lets consider this bit of code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

my_entries = []

for _ in range(5):
    x = tk.Entry(root)
    x.pack()
    my_entries.append(x)
    print(x)

root.mainloop()
```

If you run this code the follow will be printed:

```
.!entry
.!entry2
.!entry3
.!entry4
.!entry5
```

these are the Id's for tkinter that it creates for each widget you will create.
Python itself knows these elements by the python_id we can print out with:

```
print(id(x))
```

So if we run this code with id(x) the following is printed out for me:

```
54022032
59532048
59532976
59532144
59533040
```

So a full exampel of what you trying to do is:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

my_entries = []

for _ in range(5):
    x = tk.Entry(root)
    x.pack()
    my_entries.append(x)
    print(x)
def auto_fill():
    for entry in (my_entries):
        entry.insert(0, str(entry))

b = tk.Button(root, text='autofill', command=auto_fill)
b.pack()

def pprint():
    for entry in my_entries:
        print(entry.get())
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='print', command=pprint)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great this helps and simplifies my code an awful lot! I was making lists to keep track of entry count and blah blah too long!

Thanks for the help